# Проблемы в преобразовании данных в Java

Tags: java

Начинаю разбираться в Java и у меня проблемы в преобразовании `list` в массив

> /MyClass.java:14: error: variable num is already defined in method bubbleSort(String[])
>           ArrayList num = new ArrayList();
>
> /MyClass.java:16: error: int cannot be dereferenced
>           num.add(arr[0]);
>
> /MyClass.java:37: error: int cannot be dereferenced
>               num.add(arr[i]);
>
> /MyClass.java:48: error: int cannot be dereferenced
>          int mas[]=num.toArray(new int[num.size()]);
>
> /MyClass.java:48: error: int cannot be dereferenced
>          int mas[]=num.toArray(new int[num.size()]);

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MyClass {
       public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr){
        int arr[] = new int[50];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        //элементу массива присваивается случайное число от 0 до 99
        arr[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        System.out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
        }
        int num = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> num_1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        num.add(arr[0]);
        num++;
        int qw = 1;
        int as =arr[0];
        for (int j = 1; j<50; j++){
                if (arr[j] == arr[0]) {
                    qw ++;
                }
            }
        num_1.add(qw);
        qw = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i<50; i++){
            if (arr[i]!=as) {
                qw = 1;
                for(int k = i+1; k<50; k++){
                    if (arr[k] == arr[i]) {
                        arr[k] = as;
                        qw++;
                    }
                }
            }
            num.add(arr[i]);
            num++;
            num_1.add(qw);
            arr[i] = as;
        }
        int mas[] = new int[num];
        int mas_1[] = new int[num];
        for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
            mas[i] = num_1.get(i);
            mas_1[i] = num.get(i);
        }
        int l;
        int t;
        for (int i=0; i<num; i++){
            for(int j=i; j<num; j++){
                if (mas[i]<mas[j]) {
                    l = mas[i];  t = mas_1[i];
                    mas[i] = mas[j];  mas_1[i]=mas_1[j];
                    mas[j] = l; mas_1[j] = t;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<num; i++){
            System.out.println(mas[i] +  " " + mas_1[i]);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Двум разным переменным дано одно и то же имя

Comment: `int num = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();` переименуйте одну из переменных